# Reload current keyboard layout after making changes

Tags: keyboard-layout, development

I am developing bug fixes to keyboard layouts.

For now, I am not adding any new layouts; I am just making changes to existing ones. I do this by directly modifying the layout files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`.

After making a change, I would like to test if it behaves as expected. Usually this affects the keyboard layout which is already active on my machine. I am in an X11 session, not on a tty console.

How can I tell Ubuntu to reload the current keyboard layout from symbols files?

Comment: @UnKNOWn I am on MATE. Alt+F2 gives me the *Run application* dialog. `systemctl restart keyboard-setup` does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Ok. @N0rbert Will help you soon on this.

Comment: AFAIK you don't need to do anything besides switching to the layout(s) you changed.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson maybe, but what if I’m editing the currently active layout (which is my primary use case)? Does the OS cut some corners à la “switching to an already active layout is a no-op”? In that case I may have to jump through some extra hoops (switch to a different layout and back again). Anyways, I have found an answer which works for that particular use case (on 18.04), see below.

Comment: @user149408: Right, switching to some other layout and back again may be necessary if you edit the active layout. Good to know that there is another way too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/385725/91283 (originally from https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard):

```
sudo udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setxkbmap` for that. Here an example to switch (or re-read) the german `de` layout with the variant `deadacute`.

```sh
setxkbmap de -variant deadacute -v
```

Another useful flags are `-option` (to use with options such as `grp:alt_shift_toggle` or `kpdl:comma`).

The `-v` flag, for verbose, can be very useful when the layout does not compile for some reason. If it does not compile you can set a higher verbose level (integer from 0 to 10, default: 5) to better trace the error.

For more details, `man setxkbmap`.

Comment: As I understand it, that switches the layout. Fine if I’m, say, on Krakhozian (standard), and want to test out my brand new Krakhozian (programmer) layout. However, if I am making changes to the Krakhozian (standard) layout while it is active, not sure if the OS cuts some corners à la “switching to a layout that is already active is a no-op”, though there is a way to just reload whatever is active; see my answer.

Comment: strange, because it works for me... whenever I am editing a layout I try it via setxkbmap. In any case, I'm glad you found a solution that works for you :)